# Multiple one to many relations of the same entity type code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have problems defining an entity that has two one-to-many relations (two lists)

```
public class Calendar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }


    public virtual IList<Appointment> FreeSlots { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Appointment> AppointmentsList { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }       
    public String Info { get; set; }
    public Guid CalendarID { get; set; }       
    public virtual Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
 }
```

And code-first code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>().HasKey(u => new {u.AppointmentID, u.CalendarID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>().HasRequired(u => u.Calendar).WithMany(c => c.FreeSlots).HasForeignKey(f => f.CalendarID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>().HasRequired(u => u.Calendar).WithMany(c => c.AppointmentsList).HasForeignKey(f => f.CalendarID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Appointment has two PK because I want the appointment to be deleted if the calendar is deleted.

When I try to add a new appointment to the FreeSlot, I get the following error:
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception.

I have tried with this mapping too with no luck:error 0040: Type Calendar_FreeSlots is not defined in the namespace Project.DAL (Alias=Self).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>().HasKey(u => new {u.AppointmentID, u.CalendarID });           
        modelBuilder.Entity<Calendar>().HasMany(c => c.FreeSlots).WithRequired(c => c.Calendar).HasForeignKey(c => c.CalendarID).WillCascadeOnDelete();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Calendar>().HasMany(c => c.AppointmentsList).WithRequired(c => c.Calendar).HasForeignKey(c => c.CalendarID).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I guess the problem is that I have two one-to-many relations to the same type of entity but I do not know the way to make it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake in your mapping is that you use `Appointment.Calendar` twice for two different relationships. That's not possible. You would need a second pair of FK and navigation properties in `Appointment` (or map one relationship without inverse properties):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Calendar>()
    .HasMany(c => c.FreeSlots)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Calendar1)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.Calendar1ID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Calendar>()
    .HasMany(c => c.AppointmentsList)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Calendar2)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.Calendar2ID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

(For at least one relationship you must disable cascading delete. Otherwise you'll end up with a multiple cascading delete exception.)

However, I have the feeling that you actually should have only one relationship and collection `Calendar.Appointments` and a kind of status in `Appointment`, like a `bool IsFree` property. You could then always extract the free slots of a calendar entry with `calendar.Appointments.Where(a => a.IsFree)`.

Comment: Thanks @Slauma! that solved my problem. And you are right about the bool property, in fact I have used two different entities that inherite from Appointment. Anyway I did not understand which was the problem with my mappings but now I do :)

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. I have a CONTACT that has Emails & Phones. I want to combine Emails & Phones in one Entity called CONTACTINFO which can have a ContactInfoType property (Enum) to differentiate them. If there a way to have navigation properties with a default WHERE clause / condition in the modelbuilder?